# js как клонировать некоторые узлы из списка ul без jQuery

Tags: javascript, clone

есть ul с несколькими li. мне нужно скопировать первые 3 и добавить в другой блок

```
<ul>
    <li>текст</li>
    <li>текст</li>
    <li>текст</li>
    <li>текст</li>
    <li>текст</li>
    <li>текст</li>
    <li>текст</li>
</ul>

<ul id="otherBlock"></ul>
```

на jQuery делалось просто:

$elems=$("selector").slice(0,3).clone()

есть аналог на чистом js?

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll`

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych querySelectorAll не имеет метода slice

Comment: Думаю, можно посмотреть тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object

Comment: @axmed2004 `[...document.querySelectorAll]`, нужно просто захотеть, блин, там уже и ответ с етим всем есть  )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

К примеру так:

```js
var ulElem = document.querySelectorAll('ul:not([ id=otherBlock]) li');
var copyElem = [...ulElem].slice(0, 3);

copyElem.forEach(function(el) {
  document.getElementById('otherBlock').innerHTML += el.outerHTML;
});
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>текст1</li>
    <li>текст2</li>
    <li>текст3</li>
    <li>текст4</li>
    <li>текст5</li>
    <li>текст6</li>
    <li>текст7</li>
</ul>
Вывод:
<ul id="otherBlock"></ul>
```